# Guess a number using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a python program for the below using while, for and if loops:

```
# initial print statement after setting a random

A secret random integer between 100 and 200 has been generated.
Can you guess what it is?

Make a guess between 100 and 200: 180
Wrong number! The secret number is less than 180.

Make a guess between 100 and 179: 140
Wrong number! The secret number is larger than 140.

Make a guess between 141 and 179: 130
Invalid input! Please make a guess between 141 and 179.

Make a guess between 141 and 179: 155
Wrong number! The secret number is larger than 155.

Make a guess between 156 and 179: 162
Congratulation! You got the right number.
```

A Random number should be generated between 100 and 200 and every time the range should dynamically change after getting input from user

Code

```
from random import *

rand = int(randint(100,200))
usr_inp = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 100: "))
low_range = 0
up_range = 0

if usr_inp != rand:
    for i in range(int(low_range), int(up_range)):
        if usr_inp > rand:
            print("Wrong number! The secret number is lesser than ", usr_inp)
            up_range = usr_inp
        elif usr_inp < rand:
            print("Wrong number! The secret number is larger than ", usr_inp)
            low_range = usr_inp
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
else:
    print("Congratulation, you got the right number")
```

Comment: `random` module should help

Comment: any code would make it a lot easier for us to guess the problem

Comment: Hi Venkata, what have you tried till now? Can you share any code snippet?.That'll be helpful for us. Also, read about `random` module and looping constructs. (A while loop should do the job here)

Comment: @YuvrajJaiswal i've added the code..

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it, but without any for-loops:

```
import random

running = True
answer = random.randint(100, 200)
print("A secret random integer between 100 and 200 has been generated.\nCan you guess what it is?")
low = 100
high = 200

while running:
    usr_inp = int(input("Make a guess between "+str(low)+" and "+str(high)+": "))
    if usr_inp < low or usr_inp > high:
        print("Invalid input! Please make a guess between "+str(low)+" and "+str(high)+": ")
    elif usr_inp < answer:
        print("Wrong number! The secret number is larger than "+str(usr_inp)+".")
        low = usr_inp + 1
    elif usr_inp > answer:
        print("Wrong number! The secret number is less than "+str(usr_inp)+".")
        high = usr_inp - 1
    elif usr_inp == answer:
        print("Congratulations! You got the right number.")
        running = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through all the numbers in the range.

```
import random
upper = 200
lower = 100
num = int(random.randrange(lower,upper))
print(num)
usr_inp = int(input("Enter a number between " + str(lower) + " and "+ str(upper) + ": "))
while(usr_inp != num):
    if(num > usr_inp):
        lower = usr_inp
    elif(num < usr_inp):
        upper = usr_inp
    usr_inp = int(input("Enter a number between " + str(lower) + " and "+ str(upper) + ": "))

print("Congratulation, you got the right number")
```

Comment: Thanks Yuvraj. Somehow I tried on my own and brought the expected result..